# Measure Pixel per Region in Android

Tags: java, android, image-processing

I am working a project and I would measure pixel per region in a binary image. for example , there are two regions of different forms . A is circular  and B is pentagonal. then I want to count total of pixel regions A and B!

I've got a question, how can I measure pixel of the region A dan B ?

any idea?
Thank a lot....

Comment: If you know where your regions are, you could use a flood fill algorithm to count their sizes...

Comment: Don't understand how this question could get upvoted when it's ill-posed and shows no effort.